# Bounded feasible region condition

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose $M=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: Ax \ge b\}$ is nonempty and $x_0 \in M$.

Prove that $M$ is unbounded, then there exists a vector $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $x_0+\lambda d \in M,\forall \lambda \ge 0$.

I can prove it with duality theorem, but I think there is a simple proof.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to show the existence of $d$, such that $x_0+\lambda d \in M$. In other words, you need to find $d$ such that 
$$
A(x_0+\lambda d)\ge b
$$
But since 
$$A(x_0+\lambda d)= Ax_0+\lambda A d$$
and that
$$
Ax_0\ge b\quad \mbox{ (as $x_0\in M$) }
$$
You only need to find $d\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$$
\lambda A d\ge b\quad \forall \lambda \ge 0
$$
$d:=x_0$ is an obvious candidate, and we are done.

Comment: Doesn't it suffice to find a $d$ such that $\lambda A d\geq 0$ for all $\lambda\geq 0$ as $Ax_0\geq b$ already?